# Possible MATLAB syntax error?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a very simple program in MATLAB and it's telling me I may have syntax errors but I'm not sure....does this look right to you?

function  largerThanN (rowVector, n)

for n in rowVector

```
for n > rowVector(i)

    display (rowVector(i))
end
```

end

end

Comment: What does your code aim to do?

Comment: `for n in rowVector` is definitely not Matlab syntax. Did you think to look at the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have two different `n` in your code!

I renamed one to m. I also changed it to display all elements of the rowVector that are larger than n. Is that what your code is intended to do?

```
function largerThanN (rowVector, n)

for i = 1:length(rowVector)

    if rowVector(i) > n
        display (rowVector(i))
    end

end

end
```